# Почему ширина шаблона сайта 1029px?

Tags: дизайн, вёрстка

Уважаемые дизайнеры! Кто-нибудь может объяснить почему в ширине шаблона сайта используется именно это упоротое число? Не 1030 не 1000 а именно 1029, причем вижу это уже в 4-м дизайне который мне предоставляют!

п.с. я верстак :)

Comment: может человек родился 29 октября. Либо это максимальная ширина, которая может уместиться у дизайнера на экране.

/ я не дизайнер:)

Answer (score 5):

Странный дизайнер :D 
Может он когда-то нашёл пример, где использовалась такая ширина, и теперь просто переделывает тот шаблон?

Действительно, логичнее использовать 1000px: экран 1024px минус ширина рамки окна и скроллбаров. Для адаптивных дизайнов обычно используется 960px под экраны смартфонов.

Кстати, по запросу 1029px google на первом месте выдаёт эту страницу, что ещё раз подтверждает, что это фишка дизайнера

Comment: Используя лексикон вопроса: не странный дизайнер, а "упоротый".

Answer (score 0):

Искать ответ на этой странице: [gridsystemgenerator.com](http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/gs01.php?GridWidth=1029&GridColumns=21&GridMarginLeft=10&GridMarginRight=10).

Comment: Непонятно. Там можно любые цифры подставить, а стандартный шаблон на 960px.